# Convert nested dict into dataframe with sub-columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My nested dict is:

```
nest_dict = {
'Main_col1': 
  {'col': 1, 'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'sub_col': 4, 'sub_col2': 5, 'sub_col3': 6}, 
'Main_col2': 
  {'col': 1, 'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'sub_col': 4, 'sub_col2': 5, 'sub_col3': 6}, 
'Main_col3': 
  {'col': 1, 'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'sub_col': 4, 'sub_col2': 5, 'sub_col3': 6}, 
'Main_col4': 
  {'col': 1, 'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'sub_col': 4, 'sub_col2': 5, 'sub_col3': 6}, 
'Main_col5': 
  {'col': 1, 'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'sub_col': 4, 'sub_col2': 5, 'sub_col3': 6}
}
```

I would like to make dataframe from above nested dict in such way that my sub_columns will have above Main_cols and cols will be on the same level as sub_cols but without main_cols under.

I've tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict, pd.MultiIndex, pd.Dataframe` and converting with xlwings. Nothing made me output as expected. Thank you for help!

Comment: please provide the exact matching expected output for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, do you want to interleave the rows?

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nest_dict, orient='index')
tmp2 = tmp.filter(like='sub_')

out = pd.concat({'main': tmp.drop(columns=tmp2.columns),
                 'sub': tmp2.rename(columns=lambda c: c.removeprefix('sub_'))
                 }).swaplevel().sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
```

Output:

```
                col  col2  col3
Main_col1 main    1     2     3
          sub     4     5     6
Main_col2 main    1     2     3
          sub     4     5     6
Main_col3 main    1     2     3
          sub     4     5     6
Main_col4 main    1     2     3
          sub     4     5     6
Main_col5 main    1     2     3
          sub     4     5     6
```

Or:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nest_dict, orient='index')

out = (tmp.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                       tmp.columns.str.extract('(?:([^_]+)_)?(.*)')
                                             ),
                    axis=1)
          .stack(level=0)
          .rename_axis(index=[None, None], columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
               col  col2  col3
Main_col1 NaN    1     2     3
          sub    4     5     6
Main_col2 NaN    1     2     3
          sub    4     5     6
Main_col3 NaN    1     2     3
          sub    4     5     6
Main_col4 NaN    1     2     3
          sub    4     5     6
Main_col5 NaN    1     2     3
          sub    4     5     6
```

Comment: @Tomasz please edit your question to provide the expected output.

Comment: I would have:
                                    Main_col1                               Main_col2 
col1  col2  col3  sub_col1  sub_col2  sub_col3  sub_col1  sub_col2  sub_col3
1           2       3             4               5              6              4              5              6
1           2       3             4               5              6              4              5              6

And all Main_cols have just 3 sub_cols. Let's say every value for cols and sub_cols are the same, it is not in this way, however this is not necessary. In most case cols values are Series.

Answer (score 0):

I would have:

```
                             Main_col1                 Main_col2 
col1  col2  col3  sub_col1  sub_col2  sub_col3  sub_col1  sub_col2  sub_col3
   1     2     3         4         5         6         4         5         6 
   1     2     3         4         5         6         4         5         6
```

And all Main_cols have just 3 sub_cols. Let's say every value for cols and sub_cols are the same, it is not in this way, however this is not necessary. In most case cols values are Series.

Comment: Please edit your **question**, don't use an **answer** to comment. And provide the exact expected output, it looks like several values are missing, which makes the question ambiguous. You might also want to modify the example to use unique numbers when the value are not necessarily identical instead of 1/2/3/4/5/6 everywhere